# Display complicated Latex in a message box in Matlab results in error

Tags: matlab, latex

I want to display some Latex output in a messagebox.
The Latex is this:

```latex
\left|\begin{array}{l}
        u_{tt}=5u_{xx},\quad t>0,\quad 0<x<7 \\
        \left.u\right|_{t=0} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
            \arctan{\left[\left(x^2-11x+30\right)^2\right]}, & x\in[5,6] \\
            0, & x\in[0,5)\cup(6,7]
        \end{array}\right. \\
        \left.u_t\right|_{t=0}=0,\quad 0\leq x\leq7 \\
        \left.u_x\right|_{x=0}=0,\quad \left.u_x\right|_{x=7}=0\,\quad t\geq 0\\
    \end{array}\right.
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```matlab
CreateStruct.Interpreter = 'tex';
CreateStruct.WindowStyle = 'modal';
h = msgbox("\left|\begin{array}{l}"...
        "u_{tt}=5u_{xx},\quad t>0,\quad 0<x<7 \\"...
        "\left.u\right|_{t=0} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}"...
            "\arctan{\left[\left(x^2-11x+30\right)^2\right]}, & x\in[5,6] \\"...
            "0, & x\in[0,5)\cup(6,7]"...
        "\end{array}\right. \\"...
        "\left.u_t\right|_{t=0}=0,\quad 0\leq x\leq7 \\"...
        "\left.u_x\right|_{x=0}=0,\quad \left.u_x\right|_{x=7}=0\,\quad t\geq 0\\"...
    "\end{array}\right.","Task",CreateStruct);
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's just impossible to put such complicated code in a messagebox? It seems that `msgbox` does not support multiline strings as arguments.

Comment: Have you worked out exactly which commands are causing errors? I have had a quick look. For example, `\leq` and `\in` seem to be working ok.  `\left(` and `\right)` (among others) are unable to be parsed by the interpreter. I'm not sure about using `\begin{array}`, `\end{array}`, and using newlines `\\ `.

Comment: Matlab seems to be particularly unhappy of `"u_{tt}=5u_{xx},\quad t>0,\quad 0<x<7 \\"...` but even if I replace it with a string such as `u`, it's still underlined. It seems to me that Matlab's Latex interpreter can't handle quite a few of these symbols - my bets being mostly on \begin{array} (but shows the error in the wrong line). I will drop \left and right and see what happens.

Comment: So I did a little bit of testing. After I removed `\left` and `\right` the problem remained. Then I removed `\begin{array}` and `\end{array}` but the problem still remained. I outright started deleting line by line and the second line was always underlined until finally only one line of string was left. My interpretation is that I can't use multiline strings as arguments inside `msgbox`.

Comment: Perhaps worth editing your question to ask about that specifically

Comment: What about the ideas [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24674-multiple-lines-in-msgbox)?

Comment: @RobertSeifert I replaced my sintax with `{"<string1>","<string2>"}` and now the code compiles but Matlab still can't parse the Latex code. After testing, it turns out one reason why the code is not interpreted is that I escape a comma like this `\,`

Comment: Another update: Matlab doesn't like `\arctan`. It likes `arctan`. Still, I can't make `\begin{array}` to work even though it is claimed it is supported in `R2018a`.

Comment: You might want to concatenate the strings, so it’s a single string as input. There is no reason for putting in multiple strings here.

Comment: Also, indeed, MATLAB implements a subset of LaTeX, I think they have their own interpreter? If the equation is always the same, you could compile it with a real LaTeX, export it as SVG, then display the SVG in a modal window. There are Java GUI components available that support any valid HTML, I’m pretty sure you can render SVG that way.

Comment: The reason for dividing the string is mainly code readability. I hadn't thought of rendering an image, which I could put inside the window. That's a nice idea. So far, I've made a compromise: using `sprintf` I indented parts of the lines to make them look more like a matrix. It's ugly but I don't have any more time to invest in a message, which isn't even part of my requirements but my experimentation. Thanks for the idea.